# How to highlight entire area of list item using :hover

Tags: html, css, list

When hovering over a list item, see Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/22upj1yc/), I want the black highlight to cover not the entire area of the list item, not leaving any white space on top or bottom. Right now it only covers the center area of the list item.

I have tried removing the padding from ul and adding a height to li like this, but it does not work. How do I do this?

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d8d8d8;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically have updated your item, look in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22upj1yc/3/).

Instead of just `ul { }`, I have made it `ul li { }`.

CODE

```css
body {
  font: 15px/1.625em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d8d8d8;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

ul li a {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

ul li.next {
  border-right: 0;
}

ul li.next:after {
  content: "\f054";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li class="next">
    <a href="#">Next</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this looks good but is it possible to remove the space between those elements

Comment: How about this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22upj1yc/7/) or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22upj1yc/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the hover to the `<li>` instead of the `<a>` tag, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/22upj1yc/1/

```
ul li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this already, I want it to cover the entire area with no  white space at all

Comment: @jebmarcus you want it to cover the parent div too?

Comment: sorry I was away. None of them actually, the second one is the closest but I see you made the parent div 23 px, I want it to be something like 40 px and still be all covered

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding top and bottom from ul

```
ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
padding:  0 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #fff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```

And add padding to li

```
ul li {
display: inline-block;
border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
padding:10px 0px;
}
```

here is link for jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/22upj1yc/6/

!--Sorry for bad English--!

Answer (score 0):

The inline-block elements are adding around 4px space after each element (changes by browser). You can negate this with font-size: 0 on that element and switch your font size to apply directly to the li or a tags.

**css**

```
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  // removed font sizing, replaced in ul li below
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0; // get rid of ghost space after inline-blocks
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d8d8d8;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 6px; // added some left/right padding
  font: 15px/1.625em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; // moved your font sizing here
}
```

...there were some other padding issues I believe, basically I set all else to 0.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/3ezn15a0/1/